# Nurbs parametric coordinate span

Tags: definition, parametric, spline

I am using the Nurbs definition of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline). 
I might have missed something in the definition but I cannot understand how to know on which interval does the parametric coordinate span. Particularily for an unclamped knot vector. It seems that it is not the first knot vector value and the last knot vector value that defines the intervals for any Nurbs. So what is the rule if there is one?

Comment: Can someone with great reputation create the "Nurbs" tag?

Comment: I have included the tab for NURBS ( Non-Uniform Rational B-Splines),  mathematical representations of 3D geometry accurately describing any shape ( 2D line, arc,  3D curves free-form surfaces solid and hyper surfaces). Due to  their flexibility and accuracy, NURBS can be useful in visualization, animation and machine  manufacturing. As a superset *splines*  may be merged into it.

Comment: Very good ! thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a NURBS curve with a given knot vector, the following rules are always true:

- the number of knots = the number of control points + degree + 1.
- the parametric range is always defined between knots[degree] to knots[number_of_control_points] where knots[] starts from index 0. This is true for all knot vectors, clamped or not.

Comment: Thanks for this answer... isn't it knots[degree -1] for the beginning of the range ? This would fit better the results that I have...

Comment: The beginning of the range is knots[degree] or knots[order-1] (order = degree+1).

Comment: If I consider my results (I am using OpenNurbs library), everything is coherent if I take the beginning of the range at knots[degree - 1], which is the "degree"-th element, because the knots array starts at element 0. Taking the element knots[degree] which is the element "degree+1"-th gives me strange results. But thank you for your answers...

Comment: For OpenNurbs, they omit the first knot and the last knot. Therefore, they always have number of knots = number of control points + degree -1. So, the start range will be knots[degree-1].  Please keep in mind that this is not how it is done in most softwares or textbooks that deal with NURBS.

Comment: Great answer !  thanks a lot...

Comment: The OpenNURBS guys are doing things correctly. The first and last knots that many people include are completely superfluous. If you go through the calculations, you'll find that they have no impact on the curve.